# Psycopg2 problem with cursors.execute in SELECT query

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a problem that appears after some iterations in this section of code:

```
def GetTimeline(self, tenantId, tenantSiteId, query):
        connection = None
        timelineDataframe = pd.DataFrame()
        try:
            connection = psycopg2.connect(self.connectionString)
            print(f'[KeywordsTimelineRepository] connessione aperta')
            cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
            querySQL="SELECT * FROM keywords_timeline WHERE tenantid = %s AND tenantsiteid = %s AND query = %s"
            data = (tenantId, tenantSiteId, query)
            cursor.execute(querySQL, data)
            timelineDataframe = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(f'[KeywordsTimelineRepository]: {error}')
        finally:
            if connection is not None:
                connection.close()
                print(f'[KeywordsTimelineRepository] connessione chiusa')
        return timelineDataframe
```

My select query returns always 261 rows with every parameters passed. I inserted log in this section and I noticed that the pd.Dataframe is never called: the strangest thing is that problems is raised not for every request but after some executions and function is called every seconds.

Comment: There surely is not enough here for this to be reproducible.  Presumably the problem lies in the part of the code you didn't show us.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a cursor issue, try to close it before closing the connection: `cursor.close()`

I'm using sqlalchemy which use psycopg2 as driver (if not mistaken) for making the connection to my databases and pandas for retrieving and processing data.

The connection is made like this: `sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"postgresql://{self.username}:{self.password}@{self.ip}:{self.port}/{self.database_name}")` and I'm using the [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) method from pandas for getting the result in a dataframe from my query: `pd.read_sql_query(sql=text(query), con=conn)`.

Using this approach, I never had any issue on data and connection.

Example of method I use for retrieving data based on a query:

```
def fetch_data(self, query) -> DataFrame:
    with self.conn.engine.begin() as conn:
        return pd.read_sql_query(sql=text(query), con=conn)
```